# MS SQL on Ubuntu 18.04 configuration setup not working as expected

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ms-sql

I am trying to install MS SQL server on Ubuntu 18.04. Everything went fine until I ran

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

First I got:

```
usermod: no changes
Choose an edition of SQL Server:
  1) Evaluation (free, no production use rights, 180-day limit)
  2) Developer (free, no production use rights)
  3) Express (free)
  4) Web (PAID)
  5) Standard (PAID)
  6) Enterprise (PAID)
  7) Enterprise Core (PAID)
  8) I bought a license through a retail sales channel and have a product key to enter.

Details about editions can be found at
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=852748&clcid=0x409

Use of PAID editions of this software requires separate licensing through a
Microsoft Volume Licensing program.
By choosing a PAID edition, you are verifying that you have the appropriate
number of licenses in place to install and run this software.

Enter your edition(1-8): 2
The license terms for this product can be found in
/usr/share/doc/mssql-server or downloaded from:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=855862&clcid=0x409

The privacy statement can be viewed at:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=853010&clcid=0x409

Enter the SQL Server system administrator password:
```

I chose 2) Developer, set-up SA password (and confirmed it) after what I got following messages:

```
Configuring SQL Server...

This is an evaluation version.  There are [155] days left in the evaluation period.
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at 
Sun Mar 24 18:42:36 2019
The following diagnostic information is available:

       Reason: 0x00000007
      Message: Cannot open or read the persistent registry: \SystemRoot\security.hiv.
      Process: 5172 - sqlservr
       Thread: 5176 (application thread 0x4)
  Instance Id: c5829295-47bb-4e81-9889-5a20fd444087
     Crash Id: c2863467-bd75-467c-b954-3ae7f2474296
  Build stamp: c086a7e8c128fab0a270cb245183bad3f01b6afc6e38b5bc449a12e8fedc1cd1
 Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
   Processors: 4
 Total Memory: 3296792576 bytes
    Timestamp: Sun Mar 24 18:42:36 2019

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
/usr/bin/tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: Permission denied
Attempting to capture a dump with paldumper
Captured a dump with paldumper
Core dump and information are being compressed in the background. When
complete, they can be found in the following location:
  /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.03_24_2019_18_42_37.5172.tbz2
Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
```

I can't figure out where it went wrong.

Comment: Could you look through and post relevant output from `/var/opt/mssql/log` in your question?

Comment: From what I could open and was in readable format it's the same as here `The following diagnostic information`...

Comment: @Laika_Boss: By the way, this question belongs on askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find further information in

```
/var/opt/mssql/log
```

Mine said:

```
{
    "reason": "0x00000007",
    "processName": "sqlservr",
    "pid": "5773",
    "instanceId": "d7df749c-50e6-4f3b-b894-2aa7c743f33d",
    "crashId": "281e772a-5946-4349-aa9e-671cd0a3772c",
    "threadId": "5777",
    "libosThreadId": "0x4",
    "buildStamp": "70437f6583b8ef39b1ef70539ef84690980315dc7a4436c9c40015f28610e4aa",
    "message": "Cannot open or read the persistent registry: \\SystemRoot\\lsa.hiv.",
    "last_errno": "13",
    "last_errno_text": "Permission denied",
    "distribution": "Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS",
    "processors": "4",
    "total_memory": "16732037120",
    "timestamp": "Fri Apr 12 22:02:44 2019"
}
```

So I ran locate to see where `systemroot` is located:

```
locate security.hiv
/var/opt/mssql/.system/system/security.hiv
```

I didn't know which permissions should be applied, so I just gave read and write to `others`.

Then the same with:

```
lsa.hiv
licensing.hiv
```

Re-ran:

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

And then, SQL server starts, plus the permissions for others are gone again.

By the way, you can run SQL server without service, then it works even if the service fails:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```